# Python client for SockJS + STOMP

Tags: python, websocket, stomp, sockjs

For the first time I work with sockets in python and unfortunately the task is not easy at once. There is a java server on which websockets through sockjs and inside stomp. I tried to follow this example [Websocket Client not receiving any messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59946726/websocket-client-not-receiving-any-messages/60054723) , but no matter what I do, I just get in response `1002 Protocol error'

Answer (score 0):

For a Java Stomp Socket Server using .withSockJS(), you need to add /websocket to the Registry Endpoint additionally to connect with a regular WebSocket.

**Socket connect : /ws/websocket, SockJS connect : /ws**

```
registry
            .addEndpoint("/ws")
            .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
            .withSockJS();
```